# PHP check empty post data in array

Tags: php

HTML markup

```
<input name="one[name]">
<input name="one[email]">
<input name="two[message]">
...
alot input
..
```

I pass that two array data from jquery to php, i need check if the field is empty by php and exit when find one of them is empty.

But i dont want do it one by one, can it done by php function like foreach or other?

This is what i tried but fail.

```
$data_one = $_POST['one'];
$data_two = $_POST['two'];

if (empty( $_POST['one'] )) { // i only need check `$data_one` in this example
    exit('some field are empty');
} else {
    echo('field are filled');
    // continue other function
}
```

Above code keep return `field are filled` message, whether i fill the input field or not.

Thanks so much.

Comment: `Var_dump` it, what is there?

Comment: Each of them return `string(0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) functions

```
<?php
$data_one = $_POST['one'];
$data_one_filter = array_filter($_POST['one']); //Remove indexes of null or 0 - certainly name and email can't be 0
$data_one_count = count($_POST['one']); //count actual number of POST variables

$data_two = $_POST['two'];

if (count($data_one_filter) === $data_one_count) { 
    exit('fields are filled');
} else {
    echo('some fields are empty');
    // continue other function
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$allFilled = true;
foreach($_POST['one'] as $key=>$value){
    if(empty($value)){
        $allFilled = false;
        exit('some fields are empty');
    }
}
if($allFilled){
    exit('all fields are filled');
}
```

Comment: That what i need, but how can i run a function only one time when all of `$_POST['one']` is not empty? i tried `foreach($_POST['one'] as $key=>$value){
  if(empty($value)){
    exit('some field are empty');
  } else {
    echo('all field (one) are filled');
    // function, this function run two times when all field filled.
  }
}` but the function run two times when both of `$_POST['one']` name and email is filled, thanks.

Comment: @aboutjquery simple thing is to use functions like array_filter which requires no looping!

Comment: i modified the answer

Answer (score 0):

You are sending data as array. So you seed to check this data as array like this:

```
$data_one = $_POST['one']['name'];
$data_two = $_POST['two']['message'];

if (empty( $_POST['one']['name'] )) { // i only need check `$data_one` in this example
    exit('some field are empty');
} else {
    echo('field are filled');
    // continue other function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($_POST['one'] as $key=>$value){
    if(empty($value)){
        exit('some field are empty');
    }
}

echo "All fields are filled";
```

Comment: Before posting an answer check other answers. @Hoopriver already posted this answer